# Passing a stored var into an id and update attribute of g:remoteLink

Tags: javascript, grails

I have this anchor element in a `<g:each>` tag that i use to store a variable in a script

```
<g:each in="${tableInstanceList.sort{a,b-> a.tableNumber.compareTo(b.tableNumber)}}" var="ti">
    <a href="#show_${ti.id}" data-toggle="modal" id="${ti.id}" class="table" >Table ${ti.tableNumber?.encodeAsHTML()}</a>
</g:each>
```

Here is the script

```
$(".table").ready(function() {
    var tableId= $(this).attr("id");      
});
```

Now my question is that how do i use the variable `tableId`. Its for the `id` and the `update` attribute of this code:

```
<g:remoteLink id="" controller="superAdmin" action="assignServer" update="tableShown_">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" style="margin:15px 10px 0px 0px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Assign Server
    </button>
</g:remoteLink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because `<g:remoteLink... />` is generated at server side and javascript is executed in client's browser.

You must either iterate within the same (or another) loop of `tableInstanceList` and create links or you can build link with javascript by sending to client link "stub":

```
    <a href="${ createLink(controller: 'superAdmin', action: 'assignServer', id: 'PLACEHOLDER') }"
        onclick="${ remoteFunction(controller: 'superAdmin', action: 'assignServer', id: 'PLACEHOLDER', update: 'tableShown_PLACEHOLDER') }" >
        <!-- ... -->
    </a>
```

now change every placeholder to your id by simple javascript `replace` on attributes.
You can move it to your TagLib.

Usually you should be able to generate all links with proper id's at the serwer side but I don't know your gsp code structure & processes.